# CSS !important is not working in ie7 using ajax

Tags: css, ajax, json

I have the following code and for some reason !important is not working when css comes as an ajax JSON response only in ie7

```
#catid
{
  width:100px;
  min-height:100px;
  height:auto !important;
  height:100px;
  margin:47px 138px 0 5px;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
}
```

The height auto!important is not working only in ie7, even in ie8 it is working.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that it isn't working?

`inline` elements can't have their height set. Try making it a `block`.

Comment: The !important is not overwritting the height when it is a ajax response. But when if it is a direct url hit then !important is working.

Comment: It's a problem with your element creation, I guess. Could you post the code that creates this element?